# How to bundle react components which would be needed dynamically?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, jsx

We have several applications deployed which were with plain html and js. 
These applications should be completely independent modules without affecting other applications deployed.

But we should be able to load from one application to another if the situation needs which will be dynamically decided by business.
We were able to load different application screens by simply giving the relative path as there was no dependency bundling previously.

Now we are converting them to react applications with webpack as bundler.
Here we have to use dynamic import if we are going to need something dynamically. That also works on patterns which should be given at the build time.
So is there any way to achieve this kind of dynamic pattern using webpack bundler?

For importing screen components, code is something like below,

```
Promise.all(reqList.map(modulePath => 
{
    return import(/* webpackMode: "lazy-once" */`../../../${modulePath}.jsx`)
})).then(modules => {doStuff()})
```

As they all are parallelly deployed applications we are trying to go back 3 folders (i.e, root folder like webapps in tomcat) and access the other application path, which will be derived dynamically in modulePath variable.
So while importing, webpack tries to import from the chunks which has already been loaded on first application launch. But this loaded chunks are not having the screens from other applications yet.

We have tried giving each jsx files as entry points in webpack which did created independent files but if we make them as entry files, they should be attached to the index.html manually, Which would cease export in jsx to work.

My wepack config is something like below,

```
function getEntries(pattern) {
  const entries = {};

  glob.sync(pattern).forEach((file) => {
    let fileName = file.substr(0,file.indexOf("."));
    entries[fileName.replace('src/', '')] = path.join(__dirname, file);
  });

  return entries;
}
let jsxFiles = getEntries('src/**/*.jsx');
console.log(Object.keys(jsxFiles));
module.exports = {
  entry: jsxFiles,
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    filename: '[name].js',
    chunkFilename: "AppId"+'.js'
  }
}
```

The first application is loading fine as webpack is able to find the bundled chunks but when we try to load different application screen components, dynamic importing fails saying module not found.

Is there any way we can achieve this kind of dynamic imports?

Thanks for going through such a long post, I didn't had a choice but to explain.. :)

Comment: Something like this? https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#dynamic-imports

Comment: @pete In the link for given example they have hard coded "lodash" as their dynamic import module, for our case we don't know it as "lodash" in build time, it would come at run time in a variable called "modulePath" as I explained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, you are looking for dynamic module loading. You would need to `webpack` each module separately.

To load them, you have several options

1. Use the browser's native `import()`, but IE, Edge, and Firefox [don't support it](http://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-module-dynamic-import), yet
2. Use a module loader library

   3. [SystemJS](http://github.com/systemjs/systemjs)
   4. [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org), although it's rather old

In case of going with a module loader, you need to `webpack` your modules to the corresponding `System.register` or [`AMD`](http://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#module-definition-systems) formats

Comment: yes we are using RequireJS, but for that we have to register as amd module using define again right? So simple JSX syntax of export wouldn't work for this case?

Comment: If each module is `webpack`ed separately, there will be no common chunks created for shared modules right? which would increase each screen size again.
So is this the right way to do it OR the only way to do it?

Comment: `JSX` and EcmaScript 6 `export` can be transformed with `webpack` + `babel` to `AMD`. Also, there can be common chunks, each screen would load them again and again, but it's the same files so the browser will have them cached.

Comment: Common chunks were not created when each modules were `webpack`ed separately, dependencies were bundled in each file. But let me try once more by transforming JSX to `AMD` with `webpack` + `babel` as suggested.